# Where numpy saves npz with comand np.savez?

Tags: python, numpy

I wrote a script to save my training and testing data for future reuse. But I can't seem to find exactly where it saves the file. Here is a code snippet I'm using:

```
    import numpy as np
    from tempfile import TemporaryFile
    outfile1 = TemporaryFile()
    np.savez(outfile1, X_train=X_train, Y_train=Y_train, X_test=X_test, Y_test=Y_test)
    outfile1.seek(0)
    loaded = np.load(outfile1)
```

I want to just take this file and send it somewhere.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow! I would suggest you to complete your code to make sure that all names in your code are actually defined (i.e. `np`, `TemporaryFile()`). See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: from the documentation of `TempFile`. "It will be destroyed as soon as it is closed". Why not give a file that you want to know where it is a name, like `outfile1 = 'myfile.npz'` and then your file will be in the same folder as the script you are running.

Comment: Instead of using a `TemporaryFile` you should be able to use a string with a filepath (like `/home/peter/Desktop/my_saved_data.npz`).